# Convert png to webp does not preserve transparency

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, webp

Using the Google `cwebp` utility (https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp) and the ImageMagick `convert` utility, I am unable to preserve transparency in png images when converted to webp.

Using `convert` I've tried using alpha-compression=0 and alpha-quality=100, without positive result. See: https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php

The images I am working with have transparent corners for a rounded icon image.

Script being used (in Fish shell):

```
for file in *.png;
  cwebp $file -o (basename $file .png).webp;
end;
```

and

```
for file in *.png;
  convert $file (basename $file .png).webp;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

Never mind. It was my image editor which was not displaying the transparency properly. Transparency was still there. Now filing [a bug report](https://github.com/linuxmint/pix/issues/139).

Comment: after your answer to your question I checked my results with `vwebp` and find out that gthumb contains the issue, not the cwebp